# Adobe flex logging api

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a pretty big Adobe Flex Application. I want to put logging and before I implement I want to get some better understanding.

1. Can I enable logging when I use(from same server) and disable it for general public ?
2. how much of over head will logging cause, If I am liberal in putting log statements ?
3. Are there any other disadvantages of using logging in Flex Application ?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Can I enable logging when I use(from same server) and disable it
>      for general public ?

Sure, but you'll have to implement it yourself.  Using an IP Address is a common approach.  Using a login username / ID is another approach.

> 2. how much of over head will logging cause, If I am liberal in
>      putting log statements ?

It depends what you're logging, how you're logging it, how often you log it.  Taking full memory snapshots of all components is going to be a lot more resource intensive than just keeping track of the time that a user logs in.

> 3. Are there any other disadvantages of using logging in Flex
>      Application ?

It will take time and resources to build a logging system; as well as time and resources to review and analyze the results.

Your question is so open ended there is no answer.  If I were to ask you "How do I program?" or "What programming language should I use?" would you know where to start?

Comment: Just adding to thoughts above.. You could use conditional compilation to limit the logging you actually include in a release version of an application as opposed to a debug version.